# iOS: UIPanGesture and frame/bounds issue

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

I have created a relatively simple app which allows the user to drag an imageview from a 'tray' `UIView` at the bottom of the screen, and when the view is dropped, it adds itself to a subview of a 'target' `UIView`.

My problem is, when I drop the imageview into the target view, the frame is totally wrong, and the imageview jumps (seemingly randomly) to another position in the target view.

I've torn my hair out over this, and am having a massive brainfart. Is there a way to just get the coordinates of the dragged view in the superview, and then translate that into coordinates of the target view?

As you can see, i'm taking the icon out of the 'tray' view, and into the main view when the dragging begins. When it ends, I simply add the icon into the target view.

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        if (icon.superview == viewTray) {
            [self closeTray:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:icon];
        }
    }


if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [viewTarget addSubview:icon];
}
```

An image of the basics of the xib:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/obRKMaT.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the gesture recognizer to figure out where the finger touches in the viewTarget's frame by:

```
CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:viewTarget];
```

then set the icon's center to be that point, and you are done:

```
icon.center = p;
[icon removeFromSuperView];
[viewTarget addSubview:icon];
```

Comment: BOSH! Sorted. Nice slick solution. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the frame is in the bounds of its superView. So when you drop it into a new superView its not the same. You need to convert it.

This code will convert its from from its superView coordinate system to its targetView coordinate system. You should probably do this right after `[viewTarget addSubview:icon];`

```
[viewTarget convertRect:icon.frame fromView:icon.superView];
```

Comment: Didn't work i'm afraid... same problem. Although convertRect: method looks useful. Missed that.

Comment: This will work you just have to find the right combination of target and superview conversions. The answer that worked for you is doing the same thing albeit hard coded. Nothing wrong with it, but its the same approach for future reference.

Comment: Ah ok... understood. Will read up and give convertRect a more in-depth read soon. Thanks a lot for your help.